# Why does my function tell me there's an unreachable code detected? c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I created this function:

```
public bool checkFunds(int x)
        {
            if(checksBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && OriginalMain.temporaryChecks >= x)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Insufficient funds");
                return false;
            }

            if(savingsBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && OriginalMain.temporarySavings >= x)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Insufficient funds!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This code is for a windows form application. I'm making a bank simulator where you can choose from two different accounts to take your money out. This function in particular checks which checkbox you picked and checks if there are enough funds available on the chosen account. However C# keeps telling me that the second if is an unreachable code. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: Because the first if-then-else block always returns.

Comment: The method returns in the first if/else.  So anything after that will not execute, i.e. it is unreachable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a warning, because your function will necessarily exit at one of these places:

```
if(checksBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && OriginalMain.temporaryChecks >= x)
{
    return true;   // <-- if the condition is true, your function will exit here
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error! Insufficient funds");
    return false;   // <-- if the condition is false, your function will exit here
}
// this means this place in code is NEVER reached, so you get the warning
if(savingsBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && OriginalMain.temporarySavings >= x)
```

Most likely you need logic similar to this:

```
if(checksBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
    if(OriginalMain.temporaryChecks >= x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! Insufficient funds");
        return false;
    }
}
if(savingsBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
    if(OriginalMain.temporarySavings >= x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! Insufficient funds!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. That's exactly what I did. Like literally what I did. Anyway thank you to everyone for the help. I'm still a bit new to C#. I'm coming from Python so it's a bit different but I'm liking C# a lot more.

Comment: the error messages are same so i think they can be merged. like this `if , else if , else`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes, they definitely could be merged, I kept the code changes to a minimum deliberately, so it is easier for the asker to spot where the change can be made